# jScrollpane scrollbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

Working on a jScrollPane. I've installed on my server exactly as stated through the jScrollPane site. The content seems to scroll but the default window scrollbar is showing up and the styled jScroll Vertical bar and drag bar don't scroll at all.

I've read about some issues with it not scrolling on the latest jquery so I also tried using an older version but still no luck.

I've made a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8H6xN/) that shows the issue.
Any help would be appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

html -

```
<div id="subpanel" class="nav_dialog displayed" style="height: 560px; left: ; display: block;">
<div class="close_link">
<a href="#" style="color: blue;">Close (x)</a>
</div>
<div class="scrollpane jspScrollable" id="subpanel_content" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 475px;" tabindex="0">
<div class="jspContainer" style="width: 475px; height: 520px;">
    <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px 65px 0px 0px; top: 0px; width: 396px;">
    <p><img src="http://s2.postimg.org/5uxqi0mgl/cats1.jpg" alt=""></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>-</p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
    <p>-</p>
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="jspVerticalBar">
        <div class="jspCap jspCapTop"></div>
            <div class="jspTrack" style="height: 600px;">
                <div class="jspDrag" style="height: 300px; top: 0px;">
                <div class="jspDragTop"></div>
                <div class="jspDragBottom"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jspCap jspCapBottom"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#subpanel {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
}

.nav_dialog {
position: absolute;
font-family: 'Inconsolata',verdana;
display: none;
float: left;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) !important;
color: #111 !important;
padding: 10px;
z-index: 10;
width: 495px;
color: white;
min-height: 306px;
font-size: inherit;
line-height: inherit;
margin-top: 2px;

}
.nav_dialog .close_link {
text-align: right;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav_dialog .scrollpane {
overflow: auto;
min-height: 270px;
margin: 0px 8px 0px 15px;
padding-right: 65px;
width: 410px;
}

.jspContainer
{
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
position: absolute;
}

.jspVerticalBar
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 16px;
height: 100%;
background: red;
}

.jspHorizontalBar
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 16px;
background: red;
}

.jspCap
{
display: none;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspCap
{
float: left;
}

.jspTrack
{
background: #dde;
position: relative;
}

.jspDrag
{
background: #bbd;
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspTrack,
.jspHorizontalBar .jspDrag
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

.jspArrow
{
background: #50506d;
text-indent: -20000px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.jspArrow.jspDisabled
{
cursor: default;
background: #80808d;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow
{
height: 16px;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspArrow
{
width: 16px;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow:focus
{
outline: none;
}

.jspCorner
{
background: #eeeef4;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

/* Yuk! CSS Hack for IE6 3 pixel bug :( */
* html .jspCorner
{
margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the jscrollpane to generate the class in javascript.
Also, include the jscrollpane library in your document.

```
<!-- Jscroll pane library -->
<script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<!-- Mousewheel -->
<script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>



<div id="subpanel" class="nav_dialog displayed" style="height: 560px; left: ; display: block;">
                <div class="close_link">
                    <a href="#" style="color: blue;">Close (x)</a>
                </div>
                <div class="scroll-pane">
                            <p><img src="http://s2.postimg.org/5uxqi0mgl/cats1.jpg" alt="">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                -
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                &nbsp;
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                &nbsp;
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                -
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                            </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Give to the element .scroll-pane overflow:hidden and height:300px or the desired height.

I've created fiddle so you can see result
http://jsfiddle.net/8zk4E/1/

Comment: Thank You. That resolved my issue. jScrollPane is working now :)